# Calculate time difference in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table tblTask with data like below.

```
TID   StartTime                   Uid   WId
1     2011-06-06 09:30:00.000     10    1.5
2     2011-06-06 09:40:00.000     10    2.5
3     2011-06-06 09:50:00.000     10    1.8
4     2011-06-06 09:55:00.000     10    2.5
5     2011-06-06 10:30:00.000     10    1.5
6     2011-06-06 11:30:00.000     11    3.0
```

I need to write to query to calculate sum(Wid) based on time difference of each Starttime with another starttime having time difference 1 hour or close to 1 hr.

For example take first start time(2011-06-06 09:30:00.000); the nearest start time having <=1 hr is (2011-06-06 10:30:00.000) and the SUM(Wid) is 1.5+2.5+1.8+2.5+1.5 = 9.8. Likewise I need to calculate for all rows.

Desired output will be:

```
TID    StartTime                 EndTime                    TimeDIff(Min) Uid    WId
1      2011-06-06 09:30:00.000   2011-06-06 10:30:00.000    60            10     9.8
2      2011-06-06 09:40:00.000   2011-06-06 10:30:00.000    50            10     8.3
```

Comment: Why doesn't your table have a name?  Leaving out the table name is the commonest mistake in SQL questions on SO.  Also, which UID value should be printed?  The min, max, average, first, last or some other?

Comment: @Jonathan Sorry I forgot to mention the table name, the UID value of the starttime we have picked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this give you what you need?

```
SELECT t1.TID, min(t1.StartTime) AS StartTime, MAX(t2.StartTime) AS EndTime,
    MAX(DATEDIFF(MI, t1.StartTime, t2.StartTime)) AS [TimeDiff(Min],
    t1.Uid, SUM(t2.WId) AS WId
FROM MyTable t1
JOIN MyTable t2 on datediff(MI, t1.starttime, t2.StartTime) BETWEEN 0 AND 60
GROUP BY t1.TID, t1.Uid
ORDER BY t1.TID
```

Answer (score 0):

This block of code will give you the time difference between `StartTime` and `EndTime`

```
DECLARE @STARTDATE DATETIME = '10:15:45'
DECLARE @ENDDATE DATETIME = '14:00:15'
DECLARE @24DATE DATETIME
SET @24DATE = '23:59:59.000'

IF (@STARTDATE > @ENDDATE)
  SELECT DATEADD(SECOND, 1, CONVERT(TIME(0), (@24DATE -(@ENDDATE - @STARTDATE))))
ELSE
  SELECT CONVERT(TIME(0), ((@ENDDATE - @STARTDATE)))
```